# Spritekit & Swift 3 - Change ball node speed after collision

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I use the didBegin(contact) together with bitmasks to determine what node is colliding with what. I set my initial ball speed using the applyImpulse(). My code for this is:

```
                    let minAngle : UInt32 = 181
                    let maxAngle : UInt32 = 359
                    let randomAngle = arc4random_uniform(maxAngle - minAngle) + minAngle
                    let dx:CGFloat = 3 * cos(CGFloat(randomAngle))
                    let dy:CGFloat = 3 * sin(CGFloat(randomAngle))
                    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy))
```

My didBegin(contact) method code is:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    let ballNode = self.childNode(withName: ballName)

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballBitmask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == drainBitmask {
        endGame()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.showLeaderboard), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    } else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballBitmask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == target1Bitmask {
        score += 20
        self.vc.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"



    } else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballBitmask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == target2Bitmask {
        score += 10
        self.vc.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"


    } else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballBitmask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == target3Bitmask {
        score += 30
        self.vc.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"


    }
```

However when my ball collides with either target 1,2 or 3 the ball speed must be changed. For example when the ball collides with target 1 I need the ball speed to double. For what I understand when you applyImpulse to a ball the dx and dy values represent both the direction and speed so how can I double the ball speed whilst still keeping the realistic bounce effect which happens in collision? FYI the speed that must be doubled is the ball speed in the moment of the collision.

**EDIT - EXTENSION**

```
extension CGVector {
var speed: CGFloat {
    return hypot(dx, dy)
}

static func > (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> Bool {
    return lhs.speed > rhs.speed
}

static func < (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> Bool {
    return lhs.speed < rhs.speed
}

static func * (vector: CGVector, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGVector {

    return CGVector(dx: vector.dx * scalar, dy: vector.dy * scalar)
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: double the velocity on the physics body

Comment: would that work? Like declaring a variable holding the current ball speed at time of collision and then simply multiply it by 2?

Comment: why would you hold it

Comment: I thought that was the way to double the velocity. Please correct me if Im wrong

Comment: if CGVector does not allow for scalar multiplication, you could just overload the * operator: `func *= (inout vector: CGVector, scalar:CGFloat) {
  vector = vector * scalar
}`

Comment: would require writing an extension and doing the * operator also, `func * (vector: CGVector, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGVector {
  return CGVector(dx: vector.dx * scalar, dy: vector.dy * scalar)
}`

Comment: ok thanks will get back to you if It doesnt work

Comment: @Knight0fDragon updated the post with my code. Could you check to see if its fine? (FYI the extension has other parts unrelated to this as well)

Comment: they shouldnt be static...  you should be able to do physicsbody.vector *= 2

Comment: It has to be static or else i get an error saying it has operand '*' therefore must be static

Comment: yeah  I think it has to be public also,  remember to do the *= operator

Comment: Ok. Im not familiar with *= though is it the same as += but with multiplation instead of addition, or something else?

Comment: it is exactly like +=,  look at the code I provided,  it translates to vector = vector * scalar

Comment: ok thanks so much working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In the SpriteKit gameloop there are many "[udpate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html)" style functions you can put code into.

You can leave your physics behaving as it normally does, just let it do its thing.

Then, in a later update, after the physics is done - eg. didSimulatePhysics() which is called right after the system calculates all the physics do the required modifications to the ball's speed.

In didSimulatePhysics you can have some flags that look at what was the event that just took place. In the case of having just hit ball target 1, you can now double the velocity of the ball, and this will be calculated before the ball is rendered.

If the ball hit target 2, maybe halve the velocity, etc.